# Java function analogous to C mktime()?

Tags: java

I am porting some code from C into Java. I have a line as follows in C:

```
time_t t0 = mktime(&EpochTime);
```

Where EpochTime is defined as:

```
struct tm EpochTime;
```

And `struct tm` is defined as:

```
struct tm {
        int tm_sec;     /* seconds after the minute - [0,59] */
        int tm_min;     /* minutes after the hour - [0,59] */
        int tm_hour;    /* hours since midnight - [0,23] */
        int tm_mday;    /* day of the month - [1,31] */
        int tm_mon;     /* months since January - [0,11] */
        int tm_year;    /* years since 1900 */
        int tm_wday;    /* days since Sunday - [0,6] */
        int tm_yday;    /* days since January 1 - [0,365] */
        int tm_isdst;   /* daylight savings time flag */
        };
```

The C library function `time_t mktime(struct tm *timeptr)` converts the structure pointed to by `timeptr` into a `time_t` value according to the local time zone.

In my Java code, I can create static class variables along with setters/getters to represent the struct data. Is there a library/technique in which I can achieve what the `mktime()` function is designed to do?

Comment: Look into the java.time package: that's where all the modern time-related classes are located.

Comment: It would be unusual to use `mktime()` without assigning the result. It would be useful because it normalizes the data in the `struct tm` that was passed as a pointer argument, but unusual.

Comment: You might want to look into the Java JSR 310 API in `java.time.*` which class you use depends on what you actually need.

Comment: You may be interested on GregorianCalendar class

Answer (score 0):

Use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,java.time.ZoneId)):

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(
    year + 1900,
    month + 1,
    dayOfMonth,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds,
    0,          // nanoseconds within second
    zone);

long t = dateTime.toEpochSecond();
DayOfWeek wday = dateTime.getDayOfWeek();
int yday = dateTime.getDayOfYear();
```